# Downloading files(video, audio, image, docx etc) into tmp folder through Protractor

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, protractor

The scenario is, when the test cases are run, e2e project creates a tmp folder which contain mirror image of actual project(starts execution from tmp). I need to download files automatically in to this tmp folder. For this the default directory setting have been added in configuration file but after click on link, image is not going into tmp folder after downloading. It gets download into my desktop download folder.
Don't know its an rights issue for writing in tmp or something else
Further need some way to automatically download file without click on any link.

Comment: I couldn't follow your explanation. Please elaborate better (what tool are you using, how are you trying to perform this) and describe what you have do so far.

Comment: I did exactly the same like tehbeardedone mentioned below with absolute path given in forward slash. Its working fine thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [chromeOptions](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) object to accomplish this. You can use this to configure whether or not you want to be prompted for downloads and what you want the default download directory to be. You can find an extensive list of all the preferences [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc). Here is an example of how you would use it:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',            
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        'deny-permission-prompts'
      ],
      prefs: {
        profile: {
          default_content_settings: {
            popups: 0
          }
        },
        download: {
          prompt_for_download: false,
          default_directory: 'C:\your\path\to\tmp'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

One thing to note, you must make sure the path you specify in `default_directory` actually exists. If it doesn't it will still download to the default folder which is Downloads.

Comment: Now I have added absolute path with forward slash in my previous code and it is working fine  .